# Taking snapshot with a webcam (either external or internal) with python using opencv

Tags: python

am new here and also new to opencv.
 I have this project at hand - designing an application that is able to interface with my computer webcam and take snapshot and also record videos.
So far so good this as far as I can go

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy 

cv.namedWindow ("camera", 1)

capture = cv.VideoCapture (0)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read ()
    img = cv.cvtColor (frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    cv.imshow ("camera", img)
    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0XFF == ord ("q")
        break
capture.release ()
cv.destroyAllWindows ()
```

Now I think am suppose to use cv.VideoCapture.grab ()
And cv.VideoCapture.retrieve () 
But honestly I don't know how am gonna use.
Please I need your HELP

Comment: As a starter: Python keywords do not begin with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great example of how to do that here:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

The example below will take a snapshot every 30 seconds and save it to a file with a unique timestamp:

```
import cv2 as cv
import time
import datetime

cv.namedWindow("camera", 1)
capture  = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read ()
    frame = cv.cvtColor (frame,  cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA) 

    file = "C:\Python34\CpV\%s.png" %  datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y--%H-%M-%S")
    cv.imwrite (file, frame)
    #cv.imshow("camera", frame)

    time.sleep(30)
capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows ()
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is similar to what I have written without explicitly telling what line I need to add that will enable me take snapshot or capture or like you do with your mobile phone or laptops.

Comment: Without testing it as I don't have opencv installed currently and it can be a pain to get running on a Mac I have edited your code above to save a snapshot every 30 seconds (just change time.sleep(30) to whatever interval you want) and save to a file with the date/time as filename. Is that more what you're after?

Comment: The only thing I need now is to record a video from webcam - do you have any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got to edit my code and it worked
Check it out

```
import cv2 as cv
import time

cv.namedWindow("camera", 1)
capture  = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read ()
    frame = cv.cvtColor (frame,  cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA) 

    file = "C:\Python34\CpV\test.png"
    cv.imwrite (file, frame)
    cv.imshow("camera", frame)

    #it takes a snapshot when "q" is pressed and closes
    the window
    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord ('q'):
        break
capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows ()
```

This is as far as I have gotten, I need to edit a little to make it short and concise.

Comment: you should edit the question itself instead of posting your update as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use code below to record webcam capture to file :

```
import cv2
import cv
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,img=cap.read()
height , width , layers =  img.shape     
fps=20
video = cv2.VideoWriter("rec_out.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX'), fps, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
while True: 

    ret,img=cap.read()
    height , width , layers =  img.shape
        video.write(img)
    cv2.imshow('Video', img)
    #video.write(img)
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('b')):
            break
```

Comment: Great. Please share the code that worked for you and/or accept this.